# Using thrift with PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, thrift

I am getting myself a bit confused about how to go about this. My plan is to use PHP to perform the final page construction and this PHP web app will contact multiple services, which i will also to develop, for the data. Lets say one of those services was done in Java. I would define a Java interface which was implemented by a concrete class. This is where I get confused - how does Thrift link the PHP web app with the java service or am I getting totally mixed up??

Thanks

Comment: This should be linked to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2572726/connecting-a-php-front-end-to-a-back-end-java-service/2572851#2572851) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574375/using-thrift-to-mix-development-languages) questions you've already asked. It's preferable to edit/adapt your own question rather than starting three threads on almost the same topic ;)

Comment: sorry for that - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thrift is based on the use of an **IDL** (Interface Definition Language). Using the definition from Wikipedia:

> An interface description language (or
>   alternately, interface definition
>   language), or IDL for short, is a
>   specification language used to
>   describe a software component's
>   interface. IDLs describe an interface
>   in a language-neutral way, enabling
>   communication between software
>   components that do not share a
>   language – for example, between
>   components written in C++ and
>   components written in Java.

An example on how to use the Thrift interface language is available [in the Thrift tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/Tutorial).

By the use of a **`.thrift`** file, you're suppose to define the interfaces you need (in terms of types and services). For example, in your .thrift file, you could define a simple function like:

```
i32 add(1:i32 num1, 2:i32 num2)
```

that represents a function to sum two integers.

When you're ready with your `.thrift` file, you can generate the Java, PHP, Erlang, whatever code that you need (server-side or client-side), using the Thrift generator.

Refer to [the Thrift wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/) for more information.

Comment: You can check my full tutorial about thrift in [My blog](http://www.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/)

Comment: The link for my blog is updated. Here: http://blog.alireza-noori.com/programming/thriftpart-one-introduction/

Answer (score 1):

I would be very curious to see benchmarks between Thrift and PHP / Java bridge http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/. By heart i would advocate Thrift but i have doubts it is as fast as php/java bridge.